# Find the values of $p$ for which the series is convergent.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

$$\sum_{n=3}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n\ln(n)\left(\ln(\ln(n))\right)^p}$$
I have to find the values of $p$ to make this series convergent. How would I do this?

I tried doing the integral test and ended up with

$$\frac{(\ln(\ln(x)))^{-p+1}}{-p+1}$$

Where do I go from here? Basically ln(inf) will always be inf so like the only way to make it convergent is if p=1 but then that makes the bottom undefined so like I am super confused.

Wait could it be p>1? cuz then it puts the infinity on the bottom and makes it 0.

Comment: The integral test does work.

Comment: [Formatting guide](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes your approach works. Note that as $x\to\infty$, we have $\ln(\ln(x))\to\infty$, and so it boils down to computing the limit:

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{x^{1-p}-1}{1-p}$$

where the $-1$ in the numerator is our placeholder for the result from the lowerbound of the integral.

- When $p>1$, $x^{1-p}\to0$, so this converges to $1/(p-1)$.
- When $p\to1^+$, $(x^{1-p}-1)/(1-p)\to\ln(x)\to\infty$ so this diverges.
- When $p<1$, $x^{1-p}\to\infty$, so this diverges.

Hence this only converges for $p>1$.

Comment: thanks this helps a lot u only one who help me thank u